# My Heroku app will not retrieve pages that are associated with a database made in Rails. It works locally on the server, but not after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku

The database is called "games". I have it being called in a partial that then is rendered in the primary view called "schedule".

Here is where it's breaking down

```
2022-03-04T13:54:59.252562+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-03-04T13:54:59.252477 #4] FATAL -- : [8695d016-d4be-4ece-b9ae-a31c6546608d]   
2022-03-04T13:54:59.252564+00:00 app[web.1]: [8695d016-d4be-4ece-b9ae-a31c6546608d] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
2022-03-04T13:54:59.252564+00:00 app[web.1]: [8695d016-d4be-4ece-b9ae-a31c6546608d]     1: <a href="games/game0"> 
2022-03-04T13:54:59.252565+00:00 app[web.1]: [8695d016-d4be-4ece-b9ae-a31c6546608d]     2:     <div id= "match">
2022-03-04T13:54:59.252566+00:00 app[web.1]: [8695d016-d4be-4ece-b9ae-a31c6546608d]     3:         <div id= "team"> 
2022-03-04T13:54:59.252566+00:00 app[web.1]: [8695d016-d4be-4ece-b9ae-a31c6546608d]     4:             <div id= "name"> <%= @games[0]["local_team"]%> </div>
2022-03-04T13:54:59.252567+00:00 app[web.1]: [8695d016-d4be-4ece-b9ae-a31c6546608d]     5:             <div id= "logos"> <%= image_tag @games[0]["local_logos"] %></div>
2022-03-04T13:54:59.252568+00:00 app[web.1]: [8695d016-d4be-4ece-b9ae-a31c6546608d]     6:             <div id= "scores"> <%= @games[0]["localteam_score"] %> </div>
2022-03-04T13:54:59.252569+00:00 app[web.1]: [8695d016-d4be-4ece-b9ae-a31c6546608d]     7:         </div> 
2022-03-04T13:54:59.252569+00:00 app[web.1]: [8695d016-d4be-4ece-b9ae-a31c6546608d]   
2022-03-04T13:54:59.252570+00:00 app[web.1]: [8695d016-d4be-4ece-b9ae-a31c6546608d] app/views/schedule/_match.html.erb:4
2022-03-04T13:54:59.252571+00:00 app[web.1]: [8695d016-d4be-4ece-b9ae-a31c6546608d] app/views/schedule/schedule.html.erb:4
2022-03-04T13:54:59.252783+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/schedule" host=ratedapp.herokuapp.com request_id=8695d016-d4be-4ece-b9ae-a31c6546608d fwd="66.211.28.242" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
```

It seems as though it can't retrieve the information from my database on Heroku. I've run `"heroku run rails db:migrate"`.

Here is how my database.yml looks

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

As well as my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

gem 'rails',                      '6.1.4.1'
gem 'bcrypt',                     '3.1.13'
gem 'image_processing',           '1.9.3'
gem 'mini_magick',                '4.9.5'
gem 'active_storage_validations', '0.8.9'
gem 'faker',                      '2.11.0'
gem 'will_paginate',              '3.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate',    '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',             '3.4.1'
gem 'puma',                       '5.3.1'
gem 'sass-rails',                 '6.0.0'
gem 'webpacker',                  '5.4.0'
gem 'turbolinks',                 '5.2.1'
gem 'rest-client',                '2.1'
gem 'sportmonks'
gem 'dotenv'
gem 'jbuilder',                   '2.10.0'
gem 'bootsnap',                   '1.7.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.4.2'
  gem 'byebug',  '11.1.3', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',        '4.1.0'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '2.3.1'
  gem 'listen',             '3.4.1'
  gem 'spring',             '2.1.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',                 '3.35.3'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver',       '3.142.7'
  gem 'webdrivers',               '4.6.0'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.5'
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.11.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.3.8'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.16.2'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.6'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',         '1.2.3'
  gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '1.87.0', require: false
end
```

I have been trying to get this to deploy all day, and finally narrowed it down to it being a database issue. I've only started working with DB's inside of Rails this week, so I'm having issues finding what my next step should be to troubleshoot.

I've tried migrating the database to Heroku and read through these links

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6

but I'm still running into a dead end and nothing has worked. All other parts of my app work except the pages that are tied to a database in anyway.

Comment: As I mentioned several times before - process the data outside of the view first and normalize it for your application - ie setup models that represents a game in your application instead of dealing with the raw json data. You shouldn't be accessing nested hash keys like this as its a recipe for nil errors.

Comment: Also don't use sqlite in development/testing. Use the same database that you're actually deploying your application to in production. https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity